# Flutter Bloc . I can't get hold of a value to pass in the state I yield in mapEventToState()`

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm just starting with Flutter and I'm still uncertain about the logic to structure event/state/BLoc/Repositoy classes in order to use this pattern correctly. I'm stuck at getting a `location` value out of the bloc back to the UI when yielding a state that has the value as the input.

Starting from the repository I have `getLocation()` method that get coordinates from `Geolocator locationManager`  :

```
Future<LatLng> getLocation() async {
    try {
      locationManager
          .getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
    } catch (error) {
      print(
          'getLocation(): error getting current location: ${error.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

then I have the `GetLocation` event

```
class GetLocation extends MapEvent {
      final LatLng location;
      const GetLocation(this.location);
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [location];

      @override
      String toString() => 'GetLocation { current location: $location}';
    }
```

that gets sent to bloc at screen loading to present the map, and from a button to center the map on user position.

```
BlocProvider<MapBloc>(create: (context) {
          return MapBloc(mapRepository: MapRepository())..add(GetLocation());
        }),
```

then the `MapLoaded` state that holds the location:

```
class MapLoaded extends MapState {
  final LatLng location;

  const MapLoaded(this.location);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [location];

  @override
  String toString() => 'MapLoaded {location: $location}';
}
```

this is the Widget that gets built on that state:

```
BlocBuilder<MapBloc, MapState>(
                  bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
                    final LatLng location = (state as MapLoaded).location;
                    return Container
```

and finally the bloc where I can't find a way to pass the location as the input of `MapState()`in response to  an event :

```
class MapBloc extends Bloc<MapEvent, MapState> {
  final MapRepository _mapRepository;
  StreamSubscription _locationStreamSubscription;

  MapBloc(
      {@required MapRepository mapRepository,
      @required StreamSubscription streamSubscription})
      : assert(mapRepository != null || streamSubscription != null),
        _mapRepository = mapRepository,
        _locationStreamSubscription = streamSubscription;

  MapState get initialState => MapLoading();

  @override
  Stream<MapState> mapEventToState(MapEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetLocation) {
      yield* _mapGetLocationToState();
    }

    if (event is GetTracking) {
      yield* _mapGetTrackingToState();
    }

    if (event is LocationUpdated) {
    // CANT GET LOCATION TO PASS IN MapLoaded()
      yield MapLoaded();
    }
  }

  Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationToState() async* {
    _mapRepository.getLocation();


    (location) => add(LocationUpdated(location));
    // CANT GET LOCATION TO PASS IN MapLoaded()
    yield MapLoaded(l);

  }

  Stream<MapState> _mapGetTrackingToState() async* {
    _mapRepository.setTracking();
  }
}
```

Inside `Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationToState()` I tried to send a `add(LocationUpdated(location))` event and in  `Stream<MapState> mapEventToState` to yield `MapLoaded()` but I can't find any way to pass in the location. I also tried to yield it directly in `Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationToState()` but with the same result.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong? Switching to reactive programming is not being that easy but I'm getting there.. This is my first attempt to this pattern and I haven't wrapped my head around all concepts completely so I surely thought some classes wrongly. 
Many thanks for your time and help and sorry for the long question.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_mapGetLocationToState()` doesn't have event as param.

```
@override
  Stream<MapState> mapEventToState(MapEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetLocation) {
      yield* _mapGetLocationToState(event);
    }

    if (event is GetTracking) {
      yield* _mapGetTrackingToState();
    }

    if (event is LocationUpdated) {
    // CANT GET LOCATION TO PASS IN MapLoaded()
      yield MapLoaded();
    }
  }

  Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationToState(GetLocation event) async* {
    // now you have event.location
    _mapRepository.getLocation();


    (location) => add(LocationUpdated(location));
    // CANT GET LOCATION TO PASS IN MapLoaded(event.location)
    yield MapLoaded(event.location);

  }

  Stream<MapState> _mapGetTrackingToState() async* {
    _mapRepository.setTracking();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** `BlocProvider` task is to make an instance of the Bloc class you want to have. In this case `MapBloc`. As you can see, your `MapBloc` class has 2 dependencies, `MapRepository` and `StreamSubscription`. So when `BlocProvider` wants to make an instance of it, you need to provide those things it needs through the constructor. The same thing as `GetLocation`, you need to provide LatLng because it depends on it.

```
BlocProvider<MapBloc>(create: (context) {
  return MapBloc(
           mapRepository: MapRepository(),
           streamSubscription: ...?
         )..add(GetLocation(...?));
}),
```

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. Without passing the event class as an input parameter, there is no access to  the event class parameter.
 One thing dough I need to make sure I understand. Adding the `(GetLocation event)` input parameter lets me yield `MapLoaded(event.location)` directly in `_mapGetLocationToState`,  while in `mapEventToState` I can yield `MapLoaded(event.updatedLocation)`. Is this because `location` is the parameter of `GetLocation` event class while `updatedLocation`is the parameter of `LocationUpdated`event class ? 
  Thank you very much again.

Comment: It's not called param but field, and yes location is the field of GetLocation. I don't know about LocationUpdated class but because there is if(event is LocationUpdated) therefore the event is identified as LocationUpdated and you should only be able to access the fields inside LocationUpdated not in GetLocation

Comment: Fantastic! I did get it right then. I hoped it was some mistake like this(not assigning something) but I was worried I didn't get the pattern altogether. Switching from imperative to declarative/reacting programming is taking some time but I eventually getting it under my belt. Thank you for the help, and terminology correction. I really appreciate it. Good to see the Flutter community is as helping as the Swift one. :)

Comment: ok..not so fast.. now BlocProvider<MapBloc> is missing an input in ..add(GetLocation()). Why? there is no fields in GetLocation. Is also asking for a StreamSubscriptor. ..when I thought I was out..they pull me bak in..

Comment: passing `null` as input did silence the error.  Is it bad practice?

Comment: Not sure about it being a bad practice or not, but I indeed can't see _locationStreamSubscription used anywhere so yea for now maybe it's fine to pass null.

Comment: Well. I see that I did put a `StreamSubscription`as required input in `MapBloc`constructor so I deleted it (what use could it have to keep it instead?),  and I just now use it privately in the bloc to listen to a Stream<LatLng> so I always have an `updatedLocation` to use on user location. `GetLocation` event now doesn't really need to have field it's  just used to start listening to the Stream, so instead that pass in a `null might just delete field and getter..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208624/discussion-between-vincenzo-and-federick-jonathan).